# Why org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint#proceed throws Throwable?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am dealing with Spring AOP, my code is like -

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements MethodInterceptor{

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation){        
      //some code here
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
             } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw Throwables.propagate(throwable);
             }
        }
  }
```

As handling Throwable is not a recommended(since it also includes errors), I want to avoid that.
However, I am curious to know that why org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor throws throwable in the first place? Throwing an Exception shouldn't be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question we need to look at the purpose of the `org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint#proceed` which is (*as per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/aopalliance/intercept/Joinpoint.html#proceed--)*)

> Proceed to the next interceptor in the chain.

This means that it will intercept the next method execution in the chain. The actual method when invoked can throw any any kind of `Exception` and / or `Error` (*there is no way to ensure / restrict the method not to do so be it recommended or not*).

So to be generic enough (*and also compatible with legacy / third party / library code*) the developers of AOPAlliance must have taken a conscious decision of throwing the top most level class i.e. `Throwable`.

Hope this helps!